# Change image to another image after 6 clicks in HTML with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I have been struggling with this matter for a while. I am quite new to HTML and Jquery. The idea is to switch images after multiple clicks. All I need is some advice and tips!

The solution was the IF statement!

```
 var change = 1;
$('.checkOpdracht1').click(function(){
     if (change++ % 6 == 0) {
    GrowPlant(1);
     }
});

 $('.checkOpdracht2').click(function(){
     if (change++ % 6 == 0) {
    GrowPlant(2);
     }
});

$('.checkOpdracht3').click(function(){
    if (change++ % 6 == 0) {
    GrowPlant(3);
     }
});

 $('.checkOpdracht4').click(function(){
     if (change++ % 6 == 0) {
    GrowPlant(4);
     }
});

 $('.checkOpdracht5').click(function(){
     if (change++ % 6 == 0) {
   GrowPlant(5);
     }
});

 $('.checkOpdracht6').click(function(){
     if (change++ % 6 == 0) {
   GrowPlant(6);
     }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: What did you write/try and what were the problems you encounterd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like,

```
var url = ["http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg", "https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg"];
var index = 0;
var change = 1;
$("img").click(function() {
    if (change++ % 6 == 0) {
        $(this).attr("src", url[index++]);
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/frs2ez28/1/)

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frs2ez28/3/)

Comment: Anoop thank you so much! It solved the problem I was struggling with !!

Comment: I have a side question as well. Is it also possible to count the amount of clicks and show them on the html page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('#myEl').on('click', function() {
    clickCount = parseInt($(this).data('count')) || 0;
    clickCount++;

    if (clickCount % 6 === 0) {
        // Change background image
    }

    $(this).data('count', clickCount);
});
```